# Model.train() with pre-trained weights makes results all 0 while model.eval() is fine

Tags: python, pytorch, batch-normalization

thanks for your attention to this matter.

I want to continue to train a model with its pre-trained weights. When I evaluate this pre-trained model with `model.eval()`, everything is fine and the model will generate some reasonable results, but when I want to further train this model and set the mode with `model.train()`, the problem will occur. During the forward loop, all generated results will be zero after the `model.train()` statement (`batchsize = 1`).

Any ideas about why this happens?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

[Batch normalization](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.BatchNorm2d.html#torch.nn.BatchNorm2d) works by normalizing all ativations according to the *batch*'s estimated mean and variance.
What do you expect those values to be when `batchsize=1`?

Increase your `batchsize` and see if the problem occurs.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried bs=2 but the results are still all zero. I think this problem must be related to batchnorm layer in the encoder but batchsize = 1 will not make segmentation mask literally all 0 even it will degrade the results,  I am now thinking whether this is because the author uses nn.Parallel in the original implementation, which may lead to this effect.